# What is the likelihood of any side of a die appearing more than 200 times after 1000 dice rolls?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the likelihood of any side of a die appearing more than 200 times after 1000 dice rolls? It seems like I need to figure out the standard deviation for this but not sure how to do this. I know the expected amount of times a number pops up is 1000/6, but how do I calculate the standard deviation and variance?

Comment: Do you need the exact probability, or is an estimate OK?

Comment: The variation for a sum of independent variables is the sum of the variations of each. The standard deviation is the square root of this sum.

Comment: Would it be different if it was an estimate or exact?

Comment: The standard deviation for binomial distribution is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  You're expected to state what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complementary problem, i.e. the probability that each number from $1$ to $6$ appears $200$ times or less.

The result of rolling a die $1000$ times is a sequence of $1000$ integers, each in the range $1$ to $6$. There are $6^{1000}$ such sequences, all of which we assume are equally likely.  We would like to count the sequences in which each number appears $200$ times or less.  To do this, we consider the more general problem in which the die is rolled $r$ times, and let $a_r$ be the number of sequences in which each number appears $200$ times or less.  Let $f(x)$ be the exponential generating function of $a_r$, i.e. we define
$$f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{a_r}{r!} x^r$$
Since there are $6$ possible numbers and each appears $200$ times or less,
$$f(x) = \left( 1 + x + \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{3!}x^3 + \dots +\frac{1}{200!}x^{200} \right)^6$$
The probability that each number from $1$ to $6$ is rolled $200$ or fewer times in $1000$ rolls is then
$$p = \frac{a_{1000}}{6^{1000}} = \frac{1000!\; [x^{1000}] f(x)}{6^{1000}}$$ 
where $[x^{1000}] f(x)$ denotes the coefficient of $x^{1000}$ when $f(x)$ is expanded.

I do not know a feasible paper-and-pencil method of finding this coefficient, but it can be computed by a computer algebra system such as Mathematica. The result is $[x^{1000}] f(x) = 3.46799 \times 10^{-1790}$, so $p = 0.985082$.

The answer to the original problem, the probability that at least one number appears more than $200$ times, is $1-p=0.0149184$.

Answer (score 0):

For a cumulative outcome, I use TI-83's binomcdf. For more than 200 repeats, the input will be $$1 - \text{binomcdf }  (1000,\frac{1}{6},200)$$
This is one minus the cumulative probability of getting 0 to 200 repeats.

Comment: Seems correct for a _particular_ face, but I don't see how it answers the question for _any_ face. In R, for the same thing, the expression `1-pbinom(200, 1000, 1/6)` returns
0.002487549.//
Not that I have a better analytic solution; simulation gives $0.015\pm 0.0008.$ // This is not far from six times your result, but that product must involve a bit of multiple-counting.

Comment: Good point. My solution is probably good for a single specific outcome. Hence there being 6 ways to get this would make six times my result in line with your simulation. $6\cdot.024875 = .01493$ If we think this is it, I should edit my answer.

Comment: No need to edit unless you have further insight. Maybe try inclusion/exclusion. // Smallest max is around $1000/6 \approx 167.$ There is a chance for more than one face to exceed 200, so just multiplying by six is close, but not more accurate than a simulation.

Comment: So when the case for getting say, more than 20 heads or 20 tails in a 30 coin toss sequence, it is exactly double the probability of getting more than 20 heads. In this case, getting more than 20 for both is impossible. It is only when the number of outcomes can be obtained more than once is another correction required. Interesting stuff.